# Hosting related inquery Asp.Net 4.0 application

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net

We are building a public site Using asp.net 4.0 and SqlServer 2008 R2. 
We are assuming with a year our user count will be around 200,000.

We need better a understanding; for hosting how much bandwidth per month we should consider. Also what about ram/cpu.

Comment: It'd help if you could be more specific on the details of your website and what kind of content you have. A video sharing website would use a lot more bandwidth than something like a blog.

Comment: We may will be consider to put 5-10 tutorial videos in future. But currently we don't have any plan on this.

Comment: @Aysha Sharmin - This question has been closed because it is too ambiguous.  Please modify the question and add more information and then flag the question and we will reopen it.